# Non divergence of a sequence of integers

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, integers

Is the following result true :

> Let $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of nonnegative integers that doesn't diverge, then the sequence is $T$-periodic, with $T\ge 1$ an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by non-divergence.  If you mean that it does not diverge to infinity then this is a simple counterexample: $$1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, \ldots$$

If you mean that it converges (in the usual metric) then it will eventually be constant.  Periodic after that point but not necessarily periodic from the beginning.  Example: any finite random sequence followed by a single number repeating for ever.

Comment: This sequence is NOT convergent, hence it is divergent. So this is not a counterexample.

Comment: If you take non-divergent to mean convergent then yes.  However, a convergent sequence of integers will eventually be constant and hence rather trivial.

Comment: In my question, not divergent $\neq$ convergent

Comment: @AnuragA I expanded my answer.

Comment: @Mishikumo2019 then what would you characterize as not divergent?

Comment: @badjohn Great!! BTW I did not down vote. I am not sure if OP is clear on what he/she means by non-divergent.

Comment: @AnuragA Thanks.  My initial answer was too brief but I am using a tablet and hence i was a bit lazy.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong in my previous post ! Thanks for the counterexample

Comment: @Mishikumo2019 No need to apologise but thanks for the thanks.